# Using kubernetes secret env var inside another env var

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I have a secret being used as env var in another env var as follows:

```
- name: "PWD"
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: "credentials"
      key: "password"
- name: HOST
  value: "xyz.mongodb.net"
- name: MONGODB_URI 
  value: "mongodb+srv://user:$(PWD)@$(HOST)/db_name?"
```

When i exec into the container and run `env` command to see the values of env i see -

```
mongodb+srv://user:password123  
@xyz.mongodb.net/db_name?
```

The container logs show error as authentication failure.
Is this something that is expected to work in kubernetes ? There [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/) talk about dependent env vars but do not give example using secrets. Did not find clear explanation on this after extensive search. Only found [this](https://joeblogs.technology/2020/12/concatenating-kubernetes-secrets-for-environment-variables/) one article doing something similar.

Some points to note -

- The secret is a sealed secret.
- This is the final manifest's contents, but all this is templated using helm.
- The value is being used inside a spring boot application

Is the new line after `123` expected ?
If this evaluation of env from a secret in another env is possible then what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: `$(PWD)@$(HOST)` are these expressions being templated somewhere?

Comment: yes but nothing seems out of ordinary there. The values in the final manifests seem correct. This particular one you mentioned is not being templated and created. This is as is.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but deployment and secret, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). --- From the looks of it, I'd say that the secret has the new line.

Comment: This question is about how to program (sort of) a kubernetes manifest that can use a secret converted to en env var to evaluate another env var's value. This is something that does not seem to be clearly mentioned anywhere if is possible or not (i apologise if i just could not find it). Does that not qualify ? If some suggestions can add some context on if this is possible and the implementation looks correct then it will become easier to debug and fix.
From your suggestion looks like this is very much possible. If you can confirm or add to it. It would be great. Thanks

Comment: Have posted this on devOps.stackExchange - https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/17265/using-kubernetes-secret-env-var-inside-another-env-var
Do I delete the question or wait for close votes ?

Comment: My intuition looking at this is that the Secret value ends with a newline.  If you have permission to `kubectl get secret -o yaml credentials` then you could base64 decode the value and double-check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was with the command used to encode the secret - `echo "pasword" | base64`. The echo adds a newline character at the end of the string. Using `echo -n "password" | base64` fixed the secret.
Closing the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting the answer yourself. Made the same mistake today.